# Strange MySQL query results with aggregate function inside coalesce (ifnull also)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What we have table

```
id  where_id    price
1      1          1
2      2          2
```

and sql query:

```
select
t_o.*,
coalesce(
  (
      select 
             t_o2.price 
      from test_objects t_o2 where t_o2.where_id = t_o.where_id 
      order by t_o2.price asc limit 1
  )
  ,min(t_o.price)
) as WrongColumn
from test_objects t_o
where t_o.where_id in (1,2)
```

it returns:

```
id  where_id    price   WrongColumn
1      1          1         2
```

Why this query returns ID = 1 and WrongColumn = 2, if second and third (see right next below) queries return same row with ID = 1 and WrongColumn = 1 (and not 2)?

second query:

```
select
t_o.*,
coalesce(
  (
      select 
             t_o2.price 
      from test_objects t_o2 where t_o2.where_id = t_o.where_id 
      order by t_o2.price asc limit 1
  ),
  t_o.price
) as WrongColumn
from test_objects t_o
where t_o.where_id in (1,2)
```

returns:

```
id  where_id    price   WrongColumn
1      1          1          1
2      2          2          2
```

third query:

```
select
t_o.*,
coalesce(
  (
      select 
             t_o2.price 
      from test_objects t_o2 where t_o2.where_id = t_o.where_id 
      order by t_o2.price asc limit 1
  )
) as WrongColumn
,min(t_o.price)
from test_objects t_o
where t_o.where_id in (1,2)
```

returns:

```
id  where_id    price   WrongColumn min(t_o.price)
1      1          1         1             1
```

Sql to create tables is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_objects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `where_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_objects` (`id`, `where_id`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1,  1),
(2, 2,  2);
```

Comment: You know, there are numbers other than 1 and 2 you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use an aggregate function (min(t_o.price)) in your main query. That collapses the whole result set to only 1 row.

Why don't you do this:

```sql
select
t_o.*, (    select 
             ifnull(min(t_o2.price),0)
      from test_objects t_o2 where t_o2.where_id = t_o.where_id 
      order by t_o2.price asc limit 1
  )
 as WrongColumn
from test_objects t_o
where t_o.where_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: Well, my example is simplefied:
1. I must select min(price) from subquery (in real world it uses different where clause than main query for example added "is_selling = 1").
2. If subquery with different where clause returns null, then I use aggregate function of main query - min(price).

Comment: Anyway, you don't group at all. So your whole result set will collapse to 1 row. Always.